# GoogleApiClient error in lollipop and earlier versions

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, google-play-services

I've been trying to implement google play games services in my libgdx game with BaseGameUtils in android studio for some time and this works and initialize correctly, but only in the latest versions of android like Oreo or Nougat. Earlier versions show the following exception as soon as the app open:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.xx.mygame, PID: 1234
        java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$Builder
              at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.createApiClientBuilder(GameHelper.java:260)
              at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.setup(GameHelper.java:297)
              at com.xx.mygame.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:31)
              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have been investigating the files of the BaseGameUtils module trying to identify the problem but I can't do anything. Any help appreciated

*This is the build.gradle file:*

```
project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.4'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.0.4"
    compile project(":BaseGameUtils")
}}
```

Build.gradle (Module: BaseGameUtils)

```
    dependencies {
    // Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
    if (!project.hasProperty('appcompat_library_version')) {
        ext.appcompat_library_version = '20.0.+'
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('support_library_version')) {
        ext.support_library_version = '20.0.+'
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('gms_library_version')) {
        ext.gms_library_version = '8.4.0'
    }

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:${gms_library_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:${gms_library_version}"
}

android {
    // Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
    if (!project.hasProperty('android_compile_version')) {
        ext.android_compile_version = 23
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('android_version')) {
        ext.build_tools_version = "23.0.2"
    }
    // Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
    if (!project.hasProperty('android_min_sdk_version')) {
        // Google Play Services minimum requirements is 14
        ext.android_min_sdk_version = 14
    }

    compileSdkVersion android_compile_version
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion android_min_sdk_version
        targetSdkVersion android_compile_version
    }
}
```

Comment: show `build.gradle` files having dependencies for android like `build.gradle` file of `BaseGameUtils` and android module.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan  Ok, I've already paste the build.gradle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version mismatch/artifact conflict.

Why two versions of same artifact. You're injecting version `11.0.4` of `play-services-games` in your project root `build.gradle` file and version  `8.4.0` of same artifact in `build.gradle` file of `BaseGameUtils` module.

So keep one version of any artifact in all over your project or better most updated version. Currently that is `11.2.2`

---

- So remove play-service dependency from root `build.gradle` file
- Update gms library version in `build.gradle` file of `BaseGameUtils` to `11.2.2`
- Add Google's Maven repository in repositories list, From version `11.2.0` artifact now available on Google maven repo.

  ```
  repositories {
     maven { url "https://maven.google.com/" }
  }
  ```

Comment: Oh f*ck, thank you, I've update gms library in BaseGameUtils, and remove play-services and support dependencies in root gradle and now it works. Bless bro!